# AngularJS nested directives depth

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am searching for a way to mark the depth of nested directives.
Lets say we have a item-container and a ch-item and I nest them a couple of times
like this:

```
  <ch-item-container>
    <ch-item>
      <ch-item></ch-item>  
      <ch-item-container>
        <ch-item>
          End of tree
        </ch-item>
      </ch-item-container>
    </ch-item>
  </ch-item-container>
```

Is there a way to mark the depth without attaching something to it like this ?

```
<ch-item depth="0"></ch-item>
```

I prepared a plunker with this example : http://plnkr.co/edit/zC0XCeWJttroAX99Qc6i?p=preview

Is it maybe possible to pass a variable "down" to the elements ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to count the number of `$parent` iterations for every scope: this gives you the depth of a scope relatively to the `$rootScope`.

here is an implementation: http://plnkr.co/edit/jDfqB1KnFa7oDHMfVhri?p=preview

With a shared service being:

```
chItemModule.service('depth', function () {
  return function depth(scope, d) {
    d = d || 0;
    if (!scope.$parent) {
      return d;
    }
    return depth(scope.$parent, d + 1);
  }
});
```